# Does every finite Coxeter group have a unique longest element?

Tags: coxeter-groups, involutions

> If $W$ is a finite Coxeter group, then it has a unique longest element $w_0$. In particular, $w_0$ is an involution.

This is a (paraphrased) quote from Fayers' paper $0$-Hecke Algebras of finite Coxeter groups. However, considering $S_3$, we have the longest elements are $(1 \; 2 \: 3)$ and $(1\:3\:2)$, neither of which is an involution and, of course, they're not unique. So how is the statement to be understood?

Comment: "longest" refers to the [Bruhat order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruhat_order)

Comment: Those aren't the longest elements: (1,3) is longer

Comment: [here](http://web.mit.edu/yufeiz/www/papers/bruhat.pdf) is a discussion on the Bruhat order which focusses on $S_n$.